# Links and images in local html file will not display

Tags: html

I have a mac that doesn't appear to allow me to follow links in a local html file.  All links are to local files and all are broken (mouse over doesn't even work) on all browsers (chrome, safari and firefox).  Source looks fine and the exact same files work fine on my PC.  Is there a system security setting that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that the local file addresses in the links points to a valid file. As you have mentioned that the exact same files work in the PC, you should keep in mind that the file paths might be different in your PC and MAC.

Please provide some more information.

Comment: All paths are relative (and simple, basically everything is in the same directory).  And it seems that this issue is specific to the computer as other Macs seem to work.